How to handle the noise and wrong measurements due to the actuator in a close-controlled loop
My system has to inflate a rubber device using a diaphragm pump to a specified pressure (about 1000 Pa, with an ideal accuracy of ±50 Pa). The volume of the device is about 3 L.
The pump is connected with a small electrical valve to the device. And another valve is used to deflate (in a passive way: the over-pressure of the device will discharge to the room environment by itself). The system is controller by an MCU so I have the whole control of the incoming data and of the pump.
During the first tests I connected the pressure sensor (an ABP2 from Honeywell) with a T-joint together with the pump and the device but I was unable to measure anything when the pump was on. So I modified the device providing two separate ports: one for the pump and another (placed at 100 mm) for the sensor.
With this configuration the readings are better but still when the pump is on they are noisy (I can estimate oscillations of ±200 Pa) and higher than the actual pressure value. I mean, when I close the input valve the pressure drops instantly of 100-150 Pa at least.
The good news is I don't have to reach the set-point with a very high accuracy. If the set point is 1000 Pa I can live also with 950 or 1050 Pa or even more.
The downsides are:

the pump cannot be modulated easily: even if it is a DC brushed motor and I use a PWM driver to power it, below 90% of duty-cycle it does not work anymore. So I can't reduce the flow approaching the target

the system is battery powered: that's means I have to avoid waste of energy. Using valves (or even pumps) with smaller airflow I can reduce the noise and make the regulation easier but the time for inflating will increase too much

the space is limited: I cannot add a second valve in parallel with a reduced airflow to quickly inflate up to, say, 90% of the set-point and then switch to the other branch to complete


Of course I can filter the incoming data from the sensor, but filtering introduces a delay and as usual the most important thing is to have clean data as much as possible.
My thought is instead of using a PID (as said I cannot modulate the actuator so much) I can do a "successive-approximation" algorithm:

turn on the pump and monitor the pressure
when the pressure reaches the set-point turn off the pump: the pressure will drop well below the set-point
turn on the pump for some time proportional to this delta (to be find experimentally)
turn off the pump and if we are still below the desired range repeat the previous point

The advantage of this method is that, after the first phase, I make the actual readings with the pump off.
But I guess there are better ways.
Any other suggestion is welcome!

If you use a median filter the delay is minimal, it's all about how fast the software is at that point. But median filters are ideal where a spike only lasts one read cycle. The best would naturally be to look closer at the pump electronics and stop the noise close to the source. Do you have TVS and flyback diodes in all the right places?

@Lundin yes, I'm using a median filter (or even a moving average filter) but to keep the readings smooth I need to use a quite long window. By the way, the "noise" I don't think comes from the motor itself: it seems due to the turbulence in the air. In fact, moving the sensor on a different port (instead of the T-joint) reduced a lot this noise.

So it's some pneumatic issue perhaps, rather than an electrical/software one?

@Lundin my question is not how to avoid this pneumatic issue (this is a different matter and is off-topic here), but how to implement the control algorithm to handle this situation.

Well since the "noise" is rather just how your specific system behaves, then I'm not sure how to answer that other than "tweak the PID parameters". You can combine PID regulators with custom system-specific stuff.

Although... in case the valve is proportional you may be able to get better regulation by reading and regulating the valve current. I'm only used at hydraulic oil valves and there one common problem is trying to regulate a proportional valve based on pressure sensor readings - but pressure is a complex beast. Instead if regulating based on the valve current, that's more or less a linear function and you only need to compensate for resistance/inductance variations. Not sure if that same concept can be applied to pneumatic valves.

@Lundin the valves are on/off. Yeah I understand your point. In fact I'm looking for other ways instead of a PID controller.

Would other types of sensors be possible then? I don't understand the application nor do I know your budget, but would optical or hall effect sensors be options? If you could for example attach a small magnet to the device, you could get a hall effect reading corresponding to how much the device is inflated. Pretty cheap compared to optical stuff like laser readings.

It's a matter of definition of "noise" then i think - I'm pretty sure it's not incorrect measurements pr.se - you are pumping, i.e. making pressure inside the pneumatic reservoir (rubber device). Are you expecting the air to leak out of this rubber reservoir, or are we talking about a dosing setup? If it's dosing, you don't really need continuous pressure control - you can pump for a while, measure for a while, pump for a while etc. And the pumping time can be proportional to the error signal, if you really want to use proportional control

@Mark Please ask a specific question and provide some data and or a block diagram of your system

Your noise will have to be filtered. Filtering will cause a delay. A delay can be anticipated, to shut the pump off 'early'.
You can choose from several types of filter.
One type might be a pneumatic filter, a restriction into a reservoir, and you measure the pressure in the reservoir. You might simply combine the restriction and the reservoir into a long tube. You might use a second port, separate from the pump port, into the volume you are inflating.
Another type might be an RC filter following the pressure sensor.
Another type might be a filter implemented in software, perhaps integrate and dump, or lag, or median.
The measurement after all of these filters will lag the true reading by some time, and so by a pressure difference which will be a function of the rate of change of pressure.
If your pump always runs at a constant rate, and you have a known size volume to inflate, you will need only one calibration during design to estimate the offset to the reading at which you must shut off the pump to hit your target.
If your pump runs directly from the battery and so has varying output, or the volume to be inflated is not known, then readings taken continuously during the inflate phase can be used to estimate the rate of pressure change, and so estimate the offset needed.
